# I want to start my Pi without logging in

Tags: raspbian

I want to start my Raspberry Pi without logging in but I can't find

> 1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1

in `sudo nano /etc/inittab`.

The closest I get to is:

> 1:2341:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --noclear 38400 tty1

Am I perhaps doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default to auto login to terminal or to the desktop by...

Step 1: Login normally, then startup a terminal.

Step 2: Type sudo raspi-config

Step 3: Using the arrow keys, scroll down to the Boot Options (Or something like that)

Step 4: Using the arrow keys again, scroll to the option you want, then press enter.

Step 5: Press tab until you select back.

Step 6: Reboot.

Hope this helps, Dallin

Answer (score 0):

Beginning Raspbian Jessie (and I presume future versions as well), `inittab` has been replaced by `systemd`. So instead, follow instructions [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=127042). It will automatically log in as user `pi`

To quote the answer, create this file:

```
/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf
```

Put this in it:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin pi --noclear %I 38400 linux
```

And run this:

```
sudo systemctl enable getty@tty1.service
```